# One-dimensional elastic collision

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that solves elastic collision of 2 balls on x axis.

I implemented these one-dimensional Newtonian equasions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#One-dimensional_Newtonian , yet the program doesnt work as expected, can anyone giv me a clue what i am missing? thanks
My code is as follows.

```
#include "ball.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
Ball::Ball(float r, float pos_x, float pos_y, sf::Color color, sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    m_mass =r;
    radius =r;
    c= color;
    x = pos_x;
    y = pos_y;
    vx=5;
    vy=5;
    m_window = &window;
    this->setFillColor(c);
    this->setRadius(radius);
    this->setPosition(x,y);
    this->setPointCount(20);
    this->setOrigin(radius, radius);
}

void Ball::moveBall()
{
    x+=vx;
    this->setPosition(x,300);

}

void Ball::bounce()
{
    if(x>= width - radius)
        vx = -vx;
    if(x<= 0 + radius)
        vx = -vx;
}

bool Ball::checkCollision(Ball &ball)
{
    distance_x = (x + radius) - (ball.x + ball.radius);
    distance_y = (y + radius) - (ball.y + ball.radius);
    distance = std::sqrt((distance_x*distance_x) + (distance_y*distance_y));


    if(distance <= radius + ball.radius)
    {
        std::cout << "collision detected" << "\n";
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

void Ball::resolveCollision(Ball &ball)
{
   vx  = (((m_mass- ball.m_mass) *vx) + (2*ball.m_mass*ball.vx)) /(m_mass+ball.m_mass);
   ball.vx  =  (((ball.m_mass-m_mass)*ball.vx) +(2* m_mass*vx))/(m_mass+ball.m_mass);


    std::cout << "vx " << vx << "\n";
    std::cout << "ball vx " << ball.vx << "\n";
    std::cout << "========================" << "\n";
}



void Ball::display()
{
    m_window->draw(*this);
}
```

Comment: To help you people need to know: What is not working? Do you get no output? Wrong output? Segmentation fault? Sattelite changes its course? And also what you expected it to do if it worked correctly. Also specify where the error is/might be. The above is obviously not the complete code and without any hint where to search barely anyone will bother to look at it. Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just so I'm clear: It was unexpected for me to see that you're tracking two-dimensional position of the objects (x and y), but you only want to calculate the collision in one dimension (just x).  Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, I see that ball::resolveCollision modifies the velocity in the x direction (vx) of both balls.  Do you do anything to ensure that you don't accidentally perform both A->resolveCollision(B) and B->resolveCollision(A) in the same iteration?

Comment: the y is constant so the balls always collide on the x-axis. The objects are initialized as:  Ball a(40 , 200, 300, sf::Color::Red, window, 3.5); Ball b(20 , 500, 300, sf::Color::Yellow, window, 23.3);  so the speed of the bigger ball (a) is 3.5 and the speed of the smaller ball (b) is 23.3 now i added this:
    if(vx>=0 && ball.vx>=0 )
        vx*=-1;
    else if(vx>=0 && ball.vx>0 )
        vx*=-1;
 
And the output after collision is:
vx - 14.3667
ball vx -11.3889
after another collision:
vx - 12.6021
ball vx -12.5653
and then gets stuck on
vx - 12.58
ball vx -12.58

Comment: You want to use vx in the calculation of ball.vx but you just modified vx in the line above.  The calculation of ball.vx is based on the original (unmodified) value of vx.  You should be assigning the initial value of vx to a temporary variable so that its value can be used in the computation of ball.vx.

Comment: Yastanub my apologies, it's just that the question seemed so simple i thought the more expirienced users could easilly find out what i was missing just by looking at the code, just as Wyck did. Next time i ll try to express myself more explicitly so all can understand what im asking about, Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify `vx`, but then accidentally used the modified value of `vx` in the calculation of `ball.vx`, whereas you actually intended to use the unmodified (initial) value of `vx` in the calculation of `ball.vx` before it was modified by the collision adjustment.

```
vx  = (((m_mass- ball.m_mass) *vx) + (2*ball.m_mass*ball.vx)) /(m_mass+ball.m_mass);
ball.vx  =  (((ball.m_mass-m_mass)*ball.vx) +(2* m_mass*vx))/(m_mass+ball.m_mass);
                                                        ^^
```

Just preserve the value of `vx` in a temporary variable so that its original value can be used in the computation of `ball.vx`.

```
float vx0 = vx; // save initial value of vx
vx  = (((m_mass- ball.m_mass) *vx) + (2*ball.m_mass*ball.vx)) /(m_mass+ball.m_mass);
ball.vx  =  (((ball.m_mass-m_mass)*ball.vx) +(2* m_mass*vx0))/(m_mass+ball.m_mass);
                                                        ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks now I understand.